# How do I backup the structure of the windows 10 customized folder icons?

Tags: windows-10, backup, icons

I have a tendency to customize many folders' icons throughout my windows system. just one example:
[image]

The problem: Every time I migrate to a new computer or reinstall windows, I have to manually redefine each folder's custom icon. I looked everywhere for a software that will allow me to back up and restore these folders' icons automatically, but the only useful solutions  I could find was to simply make complete disk image backups of the entire system. The thing is, I prefer to only have clean installs and then populate the system with my backed up folder structure with its customized folder icon structure.

Can you think of a solution to this issue ?

Thanks